# Why do updates inside of a SQL transaction still need disk IO?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, transactions

In SQL Profiler you can see that very simple updates to a table by primary key take about 10-30ms each. On about every 10th update the write column shows *1*, on all other updates it shows *0*. This must mean that about every 10th update statement still requires disk IO. I wonder why that is. Would it not be more efficient queue up all IO until the transaction commits?

Comment: It does queue up all I/O requests to a certain extent. Dirty pages get written out in batches when a checkpoint occurs. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.02.logging.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And where would you wish to store these kind of memory updates once you update a table of size, lets say 10 000 000 records?

Where would you wish to *store* the transaction log.

*AS plentifull as RAM seems, we cannot assume it is endless...*

Answer (score 1):

Also, waiting with I/Os until the end of transaction might not be the optimal plan even with endless RAM, because then the transaction would need to wait until all the I/O operations are finished.

Otherwise it is actually desirable to write to disk for long running transactions (but in such a way that atomicity is not broken).

Comment: Why not buffer a few megabytes instead of only 10 writes?

Comment: 10 writes could very well be few megabytes. I don't know the details of MS SQL Server buffering, but normally limits on buffering are consequences of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID compliance.

Answer (score 0):

That's the Transaction Log